# Save a plotted circle as a variable in a list in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, save, geometry

I have a large piece of data, from this I have made a code that plots a circle corresponding to each line/row - the 3rd column, which is mass, represents the radius, and the 4th column is the value on the y-axis. This data is now split into list of lists with the same value in the 4th column (ie with the same y-coordinate). I plot lines between these circles if the first column in the first row is equal to the second column in the second row. However, as this is a large file, I have now realised that plotting every circle will make the graph unreadable... So now I'm only plotting the circles with only the highest 10% of masses from each row. Hopefully you're following...

This has produced a graph with multiple gaps in it, which is not ideal. So I now need to create two lists, so that the circle is only plotted if there is a line connecting it to a previous circle. The best way I thought to do this was as follows:

I want list `V` to be the initial list for my circles plotted at y=0, containing variables `a1,a2,...` where `a1` represents the first circle at y=0, `a2` represents the second circle at y=0 and so on. I then want to make the list `Vnew` for the next set of circles plotted at the next y-coordinate (y=1). Each time a new circle is plotted, the variable for this circle should be appended into the list V. (Might be better explained in my example code)

Is there a way to save each circle plotted in a way like this?

My code is as follows, however as I'm unsure what to put for `V` I have left this blank, as well as the part `(VARIABLE in vnew == VARIABLE in v)` and `v.append([])`: (note that the x coordinate is irrelevant, and that namei and namej are just counters)

```
if row2[j][1] == row1[i][0]:
    fig = plt.figure(0)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    V = []

    Vnew = []

    if row1[i][2] >= M1*(0.1) and (VARIABLE in vnew == VARIABLE in v):
        line1 = plt.plot([namei - len(row1)*0.5, namej - len(row2)*0.5],
                         [math.log10(1+row1[i][3]), math.log10(1+row2[j][3])], c='k')
        v.append([namej - len(row2)*0.5, math.log10(1+row2[j][3])])
        circle1 = plt.Circle((namei - len(newrow1)*0.5,
                              math.log10(1+row1[i][3])), 
                              radius=(math.sqrt(float(row1[i][2]))))
         plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)
```

Comment: Show us the code of what you have done so far and we will try taking it from there.

Comment: @dopstar I have now edited this so its much more detailed!

Answer (score 0):

Okay you want V to be the list of radii (ie "radiuses") of every circle that has a centre that lies on `y=0` horizontal line. And you want `Vnew` to be a list of circle radii for circle centres lying on `y=1`.

To do that I would create a list of "target lines" where i will "sample" any circle i print that matches what I have said in the preceding paragraph. I call that list `wanted_circle_centres` for a lack of a better word but its actually the y co-ordinate of the target circle centre of interest which is `0` and `1` for `y=0` line and `y=1` line. Then I inspect a y co-ordinate of each centre of the circle I plot and put append its radius to the list of wanted circles IF the y co-ordinate is the same as one of the lines of interest.

Your code would then slightly change to become like this:

```
wanted_circles = {}
wanted_circle_centres = [0, 1]

if row1[i][2] >= M1*(0.1) and VARIABLE in vnew and VARIABLE in v:
    line1 = plt.plot([namei - len(row1)*0.5, namej - len(row2)*0.5],[math.log10(1+row1[i][3]), math.log10(1+row2[j][3])], c='k')
    v.append([namej - len(row2)*0.5, math.log10(1+row2[j][3])])
    centre = (namei - len(newrow1)*0.5, math.log10(1+row1[i][3]))
    radius = math.sqrt(float(row1[i][2]))
    circle1 = plt.Circle(centre, radius=radius)

    x, y = centre
    if y in wanted_circle_centres:
        wanted_circles.setdefault(y, []).append(radius)

    plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle1)

V = wanted_circles.get(0, [])
Vnew = wanted_circles.get(1, [])
```